# How to push to js array with a key while remaining reactive in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, key, vuex

If I have an array in my state:

```
  state: {
    users: []
  },
```

And I have objects like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "some cool name"
}
```

I add them to the store in a mutator like `users.push(user);`. How can I add it to the `users` array so instead of `0:{...}` it ends up using the real `id` as key `1:{...}`?

I know I could possible do something like `users[user.id] = user` but I think that will not be reactive in `Vue.js`

Comment: I don't know about vue, but in react with redux a common pattern would be to change users to an object and then have an array of just ids. state: {
    users: { byId: {}, allIds: [] }
  } that way you can loop over/ map the allIds array and match it to the corresponding byId object.

Answer (score 0):

An array is probably the wrong data structure if you want to look them up by id. More likely you want an object, `users: {}`. An array would only really be appropriate if there are relatively few gaps between the ids.

To keep the values reactive you'd use `Vue.set`, https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats. So using your example it'd be:

```js
Vue.set(users, user.id, user)
```

If you do decide to stick with an array then there are other options, https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats, such as `splice`.

Loosely related reading on normalising data in Vuex: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-best-practices-for-complex-objects/10143

**Update:**

Based on your comments about needing both key-based lookup and filtering, my suggestion would be to store the values using an object and then create a getter or computed property for `Object.values(users)` when you need an array instead. Both getters and computed properties are cached so the overhead (which is pretty small anyway) will only be incurred when the users change. That array can then be filtered using `filter`.

Comment: Thanks. But after change to object I can no longer use `.filter` as its no longer an array. Implementing a `.filter` that takes a predicate on a object is a magnitude slower than on an array according to my tests.

Comment: @ColtonScottie Using ids as keys and filtering sounds like a strange combination. If your 'filtering' is just based on the id then you'd be better off using `map` on the array of ids.

Comment: no, the filtering is on the values inside each of the objects. See performance here http://jsben.ch/FQHwP . I need both because the index will allow me to normalise link quickly to child objects using ids, the filtering because user should be able to filter on different property values.

Comment: @ColtonScottie Only the first paragraph of my original answer concerned using an object. The remainder was also relevant to arrays, so I believe it answers your question about ensuring values are reactive whichever structure you choose. I have now updated it to try to address your concerns about using an object but I suspect that the performance of manipulating these data structures is going to be insignificant compared to the performance of updating the DOM. There would need to be a huge number of entries for it to really matter.